# How to add fonts/icons to a remote terminal running on ubuntu vm?

Tags: neovim, lunarvim

I am using lunar vim, and want to add icons to a remote terminal running on ubuntu vm.
Is this possible?

On vm, output of `echo $TERM` is `xterm-256color`.
I tried the steps given here https://www.lunarvim.org/docs/installation/post-install#install-a-nerd-font.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with remote terminal?

Comment: A vm on cloud. I `ssh` into it

Comment: and did you configure your terminal to use those fonts?

Comment: I configured the vm shell and failed.
I was able to configure the terminal (iTerm) in my local system with success.

Comment: What exactly means `failed` in this context? please give concrete error messages. Also, you do not have to configure the vm shell. You need to configure your terminal to use those fonts. So are you sure your terminal uses the correct font?

Comment: I have configured iTerm before to use the correct fonts.
I will try to configure my iTerm again as I am using a different system from the one I was before.

Comment: Worked after I configured iTerm